# In scrollable vertical menu, submenu not showing on right side

Tags: html, css, menu

After adding `position:fixed` and `overflow:scroll` property menu is scrolled but  submenu does not show on right side bar or when I remove property `overflow` then right side bar menu shows but parent menu does not scroll.

```
  <nav id="cssmenu" style="display:none">
    <ul class="level0_category">
    <li class="parentMenus"><a href="#"> Men's Corner </a></li>
    <li class="parentMenus"><a href="#">   Women's Corner </a></li>
    <li class="parentMenus"><a href="#">  House of Electronics </a>
    <ul class="level1_category">
    <li><a href="#">Laptop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">AC</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Refrigerator</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

```
 nav#cssmenu{margin:0 auto;position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 350px;left: -600px}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jgiQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msAXI.png)

Comment: Make fiddle plz

Comment: Your first problem is the punctation.

Comment: I don't know punctuation can you please describe?

Comment: @MayankVadiya please check this URL http://104.236.212.58/dev/